# how can I send parameters in registry file?

Tags: registry, windows-ce, symbols

I am working on application on windows ce and i need to install compact .Net Framework 0.2 
when the symbol device start 
and I make this reg file

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\Startup\Programs\Prog10]
"Name"="\windows\wceload.exe" ,"/noaskdest/noui"
"Command"="\Application\Framework\NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab"
"Continue"=dword:0
"ColdBootOnly"=dword:1
```

but I got 2 problems

1. every time to start the "cab" file it ask for the path
2. every time when the install operation finished the "cab" file will deleted

how can i fix this reg file to install this cab file without asking for the path or deleting the original "cab" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok, I have found the correct syntax, as follows. Works perfectly, thanks for your help.
The 2 parameters needed are :

/delete 0 /noaskdest

Using /delete 0 allows the .cab file to not be deleted after the install is done.

Using /noaskdest specifies that the user is not prompted for the installation directory. If this parameter is used, other parameters such as the .cab file path are ignored, and the default directory specified in the DefaultInstall section of the .inf file is used.

See [Wceload Tool on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504595.aspx) for more details.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\Startup\Programs\Prog11] 
"Name"="\windows\wceload.exe" 
"Command"="/delete 0 /noaskdest /noui \Windows\2_xsymbol.all.arm.cab" 
"Continue"=dword:0 
"ColdBootOnly"=dword:1
```